# Regular non-trivial tournament with diameter 2

Tags: graph-theory

I want to show that the regular tournament is going to have a diameter of 2 .I started to think about that the maximum score is going to be achieved for every vertex in which then the result follows by a theorem that it's going to have a diameter of 2 .How to show that's it's going to have the maximum score for each vertex  ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  By diameter of a tournament, one might mean the diameter of a graph whose nodes are competitors and whose edges are the pairs assigned to play/compete.  If every competitor plays every other, then the diameter would be one.  I think you need to explain what restrictions are imposed by having a *regular tournament*.

Comment: It's the max distance in the digraph .

Comment: Regular tournment implies that for each vertex od(v)=Id (v)

Comment: In terms of competitions .The vertices are the competitors and the out degrees are the victories .For example (u,v) is an arc if u defeats v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not correct to say "the" regular tournament, because for any sufficiently large odd $n$, there are multiple regular tournaments we can define on $n$ vertices.

You can show that any regular tournament has diameter $2$ by contradiction. Suppose that there are vertices $v$ and $w$ such that we can't get from $v$ to $w$ in $1$ or $2$ steps. Then:

- The edge from $v$ to $w$ must be oriented $w \to v$.
- For every vertex $x$ such that the edge $vx$ is oriented $v \to x$, the edge $wx$ must be oriented $w \to x$ (if not, we'd be able to go from $v$ to $x$ to $w$.)

But then the out-degree of $w$ is least one more than the out-degree of $v$ (it has all the out-neighbors that $v$ does, plus $v$ itself), which is a contradiction.